# MPVolumeView AirPlay Button Not Visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, mpvolumeview

I have started using `MPVolumeView` in my app, however the Air Play button doesn't appear at all. Even though I have more than one Air Play device available to send my `AVPlayer` audio to on the network. These can be seen if checking Air Play from the Control Center for example.

Here is the code I have:

```
myVolumeView = [MPVolumeView new];
[myVolumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:YES];
[myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
myVolumeView.frame = _volumePanel.bounds;
[myVolumeView sizeToFit];
_myVolumeView.autoresizingMask = UIAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[_volumePanel addSubview:myVolumeView];
```

Pretty simple stuff. I have an `AVPlayer` that runs some music and that's it. Interestingly, if I select another Air Play device from the Control Center it forces the Air Play button to appear in app on my `MPVolumeView`, but it is kind of glitchy.

If in Xcode I click the Debug Hierarchy Mode button above the console I can see the Air Play button in my UI, however it's Alpha is 0.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Is your Apple TV connected via Ethernet? If yes, try wifi instead.

Comment: I have seen the same strange thing. The AirPlay button does not appear (even though my Apple TV 4 is online via Wifi). If I tap the AirPlay button in control panel, the button appears, but it disappears again when I hide the AirPlay Popover. Weird! Will keep looking.

Comment: having same issue

Comment: Found a trick here to display permanently airplay button: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787632

Answer (score 2):

it's a complete and utter hack but it works

```
   MPVolumeView* airplayButton = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];

   for (UIButton *button in airplayButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [button addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        }
    }
```

Then in the observer

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] intValue] != 1)
    {
        UIButton *airplay = (UIButton *)object;
        [airplay setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

don't forget to turn the observer off in the dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc
{    
    for (UIButton *button in _airplayButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [button removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha"];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Swift Version]**

Create following functions:

```
    func fixAirPlayButton() {
        guard let routeButton = airPlayButton.subviews.filter({$0 is UIButton}).first else { return }
        routeButton.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "alpha", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard let btnObject = object as? UIButton, let change = change else { return}
        guard let newChange = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Int, newChange != 1 else { return }
        btnObject.alpha = 1.0
    }

    func removeAirPlayButtonFix() {
        guard let routeButton = airPlayButton.subviews.filter({$0 is UIButton}).first else { return }
        routeButton.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "alpha")
    }
```

And use them when needed, example:

```
    let airPlayButton = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fixAirPlayButton()
    }

    deinit {
        removeAirPlayButtonFix()
    }
```